# Wrap a link which is in a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to wrap a link which is in a div:

This :

```
<div id="hello">

http://google.fr/646564897564/8977748946

</div>
```

will be:

```
<div id="hello">
<div id="wrap">
http://google.fr/646564897564/8977748946
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/R44pn/

**JS**

```
var outer = document.getElementById("hello");
outer.innerHTML = "<div id='wrap'>"+outer.innerHTML+"</div>"
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<div id="hello">
    <div id="wrap">
        http://google.fr/646564897564/8977748946
    </div>
</div>
```

with **JQuery**

```
$("#hello").html("<div id='wrap'>"+$("#hello").html()+"</div>")
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/q27Sw/

hope it helps

Comment: When I try this : its not working : var outer = document.getElementById("url_re");
outer.innerHTML = "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location = '"+outer.innerHTML+"''</script>"

Comment: Well, I have an url in a page. I want to put a redirection script surround this url in order to redirect the visitor

Comment: you want the user to click that url before he's redirected to the page?

Comment: Do you think is that possible ?

Comment: have a look here if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript

Answer (score 3):

Making use of jQuery you can use the [wrapInner](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) function:

```
var outer = $("#hello");
outer.wrapInner('<div id="wrap">);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R44pn/6/